# How to achieve origami effect with 3D transforms

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make an origami effect on a div and i don't really know how. I will upload 2 pictures of a papper sheet to see what i mean[image: This is my current div]

[image: and this is what i want to change.]

How do i transform a div like this? I want it to have the same origami effect

Comment: 1.) write some code to at least try

Comment: i know how to  translate a div on axis, xyz but i don't know how to edit the same div to have diiferent properties and also i don't know how to make that curve on the middle. Can i make 2 different divs, one for the left part and one for the right part but that curve in the middle? how do i make it? i want to make an origami unfold effect using 3d and that's what i need to know in order to make it

Comment: There is no way currently to achieve that effect with a single div element, as  3d transformations do not cover three-dimensional "bending".

Comment: ok, and if i have 2 or 3 div, how do i make that curve in the middle? i want to make an annimation that folds/unfolds some divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play around with heights, widths, and borders to change the dimensions to what you want.

```css
 body {
   padding: 150px 150px;
 }

/* Horizontal part of the ribbon */
 .fribbon {
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 60px; 
    background: #e7e7e7;     
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    }

/* Vertical part of the ribbon */
.fribbon:after {
    content: "";    
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
    border-bottom: 60px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  
    /* Brwoser-specific rules */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    }

/* Shadow part of the ribbon */    
    .fribbon:before {
    content: "";    
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 60px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
     
    /* Brwoser-specific rules */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -ms-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(80deg);
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    }
```

```html
<div class="fribbon"></div>
```